# Set identity column back to 0 in datatable (contained in a DS not linked to a datatabase)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I'm using VB.Net and VS 2012.  I have a dataset that has a few datatables.  One of the datatables has an identity column that increments by 1 and starts with a seed of 0.  The user flow goes like this:

1. User opens form
2. Form displays datatable1, including identity column
3. User hides form, datatable2 is cleared and disposed
4. User reopens form, datatable is refilled, but identity column starts now from where it left off previously

I need to make sure that everytime the table is cleared, the identity column restarts back from 0.  How can I do this?

edit: Here is a little background on the datatable/dataset.  The dataset has a datatable with 4 columns.  One is an column with a seed of 0, incrementing by 1.  Referred to as identitycol.  The dataset is not hooked up to a database, here is how it is filled:

```
    dsVW_BCL_DATA = GlobalVariables.acctInit.BCL_Data(GlobalVariables.intJudgeID, GlobalVariables.AppearanceDate) 'Pull data to a generic created dataset
    ChgltrDataSet.gridsource.Clear() 'clear table in project dataset (chgltrdataset)
    ChgltrDataSet.gridsource_backup.Clear() 'clear backup table in project dataset
    'MUST RESET IDENTITYCOL TO 0 'This is where I feel I should reset the identitycol
    ChgltrDataSet.gridsource.Merge(dsVW_BCL_DATA.Tables(0)) 'Merge existing table gridsource with generic created dataset
    frmFinBatchChrg2.gridFinancial.DataSource = Me.ChgltrDataSet.gridsource 'Set datasource
```

Comment: Can't get to VS to try this at the moment so not posting as an answer - what if you use DataTable.Reset() before repopulating - does that work?

Comment: @CHill60 nope :/.  When I do that before repopulating, it tells me the column doesn't exist.  Some of the data displays in the datagridview, but only if i re-sort the columns.  I don't think that will solve this issue unfortunately.

Comment: how did you use the `dataSet` and `dataTable`, can you share with us?

Comment: @spajce yes, code is above

Comment: you can modify the `DataRow` of your `DataTable` to start 0.

Comment: @spajce can you elaborate on what you mean? Are you saying make the first row 0 everytime I load?  Would this stop the others from incrementing ? i'm going to try that but i'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: @spajce have tried this: dataset.datatable.Rows(0)("identitycol") = 0 right after the table is filled, but doesn't seem to do anything except for modify the first row

Comment: yes, because the only you have been modified is the rowIndex = 0, so the question is, how to modify all the dataRow base on the rowIndex in your `DataTable`?, you have a good clue now. `:D`

Answer (score 1):

I know I am answering this too late but I just solved the same problem with my project so someone may find it useful.

This problem is related with the Identity mechanism implementation in the DataSet. In order to correctly reset the Identity columns in a datatable you have to do it with a specific order. The following code solved my problem:

```
    myDataSet.Clear()
    myDataSet.myDataTable.Columns("ID").AutoIncrementStep = -1
    myDataSet.myDataTable.Columns("ID").AutoIncrementSeed = -1
    myDataSet.myDataTable.Columns("ID").AutoIncrementStep = 1
    myDataSet.myDataTable.Columns("ID").AutoIncrementSeed = 1 

    'Note: "ID" is the column name in the DataTable
```

As you can see the order of the commands is very important. First we set the AutoIncrementStep property of the column to -1 and then the AutoIncrementSeed property to -1. After that we set them back to where we want but in the same order.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

DBCC CHECKIDENT('', RESEED, 0)

this reseeds the identity column from 1

Comment: is this t-sql?  there is no actual sql database behind the datatable, so i need to reset it from within the datatable that lives on the dataset.  i ended up getting rid of the identity column and used something else to solve this problem, but i will mark your answer as correct as long as you can use this from within the vb language, and doesn't require a sql connection